# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-templates

forms.py:

```
class ImportExcelForm(Form):
    file  = forms.FileField(attrs={'class':'rounded_list',})
```

I'm trying to add css class to my `filefield` in forms.I am getting this error `"__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'"`

What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`attrs` is not an argument to the field, it's an argument to the widget.

```
file = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'rounded_list'}))
```

Note that some browsers don't allow styling of the file input.

Comment: I tried with your answer,getting this error"Tried contact_list in module incident.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'FileWidget'"

Comment: Sorry, should have been [`FileInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.FileInput), corrected.

Comment: Why would you want to hide the button? Then there'd be no way of choosing and uploading a file.

Comment: should that be `forms.FileField` ?

Answer (score 3):

Even though the solution posted by @Daniel Roseman is also the one recommended in Django docs, it still didn't work for me. What worked for me is the following:

```
class ImportExcelForm(Form):
    file  = forms.FileField()
    file.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'rounded_list'})
```

Comment: This is helpful, for some solution by @Daniel doesn't work for me: `type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.ChoiceField(attrs={'disabled': 'disabled'}))` but this form works `type = forms.ChoiceField() type.widget.attrs.update({'disabled': 'disabled'})`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when using **the form field [forms.IntegerField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield)** for **"widgets"** as shown below:

```py
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {           # Here
            'quantity': forms.IntegerField(attrs={
                'size':'4',
                'max': '99',
                'min': '1',
            }),
        }
```

So, I changed it to **the widget [forms.NumberInput()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#numberinput)** for **"widgets"** as shown below, then, the error was solved:

```py
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {           # Here
            'quantity': forms.NumberInput(attrs={   
                'style': 'width:6ch',
                'max': '99',
                'min': '1',
            }),
        }
```

In addition, I could also use **the widget [forms.TextInput()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#textinput)** for **"widgets"** as shown below, then, the error was also solved:

```py
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {           # Here
            'quantity': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'type': 'number',  
                'style': 'width:6ch',
                'max': '99',
                'min': '1',
            }),
        }
```