# Django Error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-widget

I'm  trying to create a form where I'm getting certain details from the user.

I have defined fields in `forms.py` and I'm also defining other attributes like *placeholder* and *css class* using django `widget` system. But it is showing me a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'
```

Following is my code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Contact(models.Model):
    your_name = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    your_email = models.EmailField()
    your_subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    your_comment = models.TextField(max_length=200)
 
 def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, TextInput, EmailField
from .models import Contact

class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('your_name', 'your_email', 'your_subject', 'your_comment')
        widgets = {
            'your_name' : TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name *', 'class': 'form-control'}),
            'your_email' : EmailField(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email *', 'class': 'form-control'}),
            'your_subject' : TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Subject *', 'class': 'form-control'}),
            'your_comment' : Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Comment *', 'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

I've read [Django docs for Overriding default fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) and also this question [**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482432/init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-attrs) but cannot fix the error.

I am quite new to Python and Django and would appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: `EmailField` is a just that a `Field` which can't be set as a widget, if you tried you'd run into the below problem, you want `EmailInput` which is the widget for `EmailField`.

First, `TextInput` and `Textarea` accept the keyword argument `attrs` in their `__init__`. So, these are fine.

Look at this line:

```
EmailField(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email *', 'class': 'form-control'}),
```

`EmailField` is a subclass of `CharField` which in turn is a subclass of `Field`. Throughout this hierarchy `attrs` will be passed along until it hits `Field` which doesn't accept `attrs`.

For reference here's the `__init__` for `Field`:

```
  def __init__(self, required=True, widget=None, label=None, initial=None,
               help_text='', error_messages=None, show_hidden_initial=False,
               validators=(), localize=False, disabled=False, label_suffix=None):
```

The `__init__` for `CharField`:

```
 def __init__(self, max_length=None, min_length=None, strip=True, empty_value='', *args, **kwargs)

      ....
      super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      # attrs is passed to Field -> error
```

The `__init__` for `EmailField`:

```
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EmailField, self).__init__(*args, strip=True, **kwargs)
    # attrs is passed to CharField
```

There is a ***widget*** argument that is accepted in which you can place a widget that *does* accept the `attrs` keyword.

Comment: I have placed the `EmailField` statement in `widget` only or probably I have done that in an incorrect way.

Comment: Yes, and that's the problem. EmailField is a `Field` which takes a widget. It can't be set as a widget.

Answer (score 3):

The error is in line

```
'your_email' : EmailField(attrs={}),
```

`EmailField` is a field, not a widget. Default widget for `EmailField` is `EmailIput`.

You need to provide a widget:

```
'your_email' : EmailInput(attrs={}),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from .models import Contact

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('sender_name','sender_email')
        widgets = {
            'sender_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter sender name'}),
        }
```

**import forms and access the form fields with . operator**

Answer (score 0):

You use **the form field [forms.EmailField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#emailfield)** for **"widgets"** which is wrong:

```py
widgets = {
    # ...
    'your_email' : EmailField(attrs={...}), # Wrong
    # ...
}
```

So, instead, you need to use **the widget [forms.EmailInput()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#emailinput)** for **"widgets"** which is correct:

```py
widgets = {
    # ...
    'your_email' : EmailInput(attrs={...}), # Correct
    # ...
}
```